# Change Apple ID from "only valid for purchases in" another country

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I've an iPhone 7 Plus. I already created my Apple ID in Sri Lanka. Now I live in Japan. I want to set my App Store country/region to Japan. How do I do it?

[image]

Comment: Depending on your future plans it might be easier to create a new Apple ID just for the Japan store.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your App Store country with the Support document by Apple which is given below. Please note that all your current subscriptions will be cancelled.

1. On your device, tap Settings > [your name] > iTunes & App Store.
2. Tap your Apple ID.  If you're not signed in, sign in with the Apple ID and password that you use with the iTunes Store.
3. Tap View Apple ID. You might be asked to authenticate your Apple ID.
4. Tap Country/Region.
5. Tap your new country or region, then tap Next.
6. Review the Terms and Conditions and Apple Privacy Policy, then tap Agree if you agree.
7. In the prompt that appears, tap Agree.
8. Select a payment method and enter your payment information.
9. Enter your billing address and tap Next.

[Change your Apple ID country or region](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389)

Comment: Please do not provide link-only answers. Instead, summarize the content of the link, copying and pasting as necessary, so if the link goes away, the content is still present.

Comment: @tubedogg I have explained the process now.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to "settings"
2. select "General"
3. select "language and region"
4. select "Region" and change to Japan

Answer (score -1):

This can be done from the Settings on any iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch:

- Open Settings, and go to “iTunes & App Stores” Tap on the Apple ID
- Enterr the associated password
- Choose “Country/Region”
- Select the new country to associate the account with

Check http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/24/change-country-itunes-app-store/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Your answer looks exactly the same as previous answers.  To avoid having your answer deleted or downvoted, please [edit] it to add info that's substantially different that existing answers.  - From Review